# MYSQL query table and replace results Wildcard?

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to replace part of the data in a cell. For example, if I have the following URL in a cell, www.website.com/p=1113, can I replace www.website.com but leave p=1113? With a final result of www.newwebsite.com/p=1113

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To replace `website` with `newwebsite`, You may want to use `REPLACE()` method as below:

```
       SELECT REPLACE('www.website.com/p=1113', 'website', 'newwebsite');
```

This will result into:

```
        www.newwebsite.com/p=1113
```

Comment: so could I do SELECT REPLACE('www.website.com'*, 'website','newwebsite') -- because each cell is different as far a p=1113.. Make sense? Thanks so much

Comment: you can't have wildcard with replace() , it only takes fix string

Comment: @Bungdaddy: You may want to use the columnName instead of providing statis string. Also if you want replace in conjunction of `LEFT()` and `RIGHT()` functions i.e. get the left part, replace and concat with right part.